# WooCommerce serialized meta value array in wp_postmeta table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am inserting items and attributes via SQL. Everything works fine, but i cannot figure it out how the _product_attributes in  wp_postmeta

I understand the logic, except the s:7:"pa_hrup" <-- where do i get 7
and s:31:"pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go" <-- where do i get 31..

```
a:2:{s:7:"pa_hrup";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_hrup";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:31:"pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:31:"pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **meta data string serialized array** and `s:31` is the length of `pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go` in this case. `a:6` is the number ok key/value pairs items for each array *(or sub array)*.

So a seriallized array:

- always start with `a:` for array, plus the number of items key/value pairs in it and `:`.
- then `{` for items start
- then `s:` for string, plus the lenght of the string item (key or value) and `:`, plus the key or value string.
- then `;` to separate each key or value component
- then `}` for items end

**Serialized arrays**, can be **unserialized** using WordPress [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) *(or `unserialize()` in PHP)*. 
A **normal array** can be **serialized** using using WordPress [`maybe_serialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) *(or `serialize()` in PHP)*.

Wordpress functions like add_post_meta() or update_post_meta() will always serialize an arrays before saving a `meta_value` in `wp_postmeta` table.

Same thing for WooCommerce with some related `WC_Data` method as `save()` on [CRUD Objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) and all related data stores classes.

using [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) on your serialized string array will give:

```
$values = array( 
    'pa_hrup' => array(
        'name'         => 'pa_hrup',
        'value'        => '',
        'position'     => '0',
        'is_visible'   => '1',
        'is_variation' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy'  => '1'
    ),
    'pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go' => array(
        'name'         => 'pa_kapaciteta-rezervoarja-za-go',
        'value'        => '',
        'position'     => '1',
        'is_visible'   => '1',
        'is_variation' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy'  => '1'
    )
);
```